# play2-auth don't recognize user after login

Tags: authentication, playframework, authorization, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to implement a login with play2-auth and playframework 2.2.0, I implemented the logic from the last branch using async, after a success login the Home action don't recognize the logged user and redirect to login again, some code:

The AuthConfig trait:

```
trait AuthConfigImpl extends AuthConfig {

 type Id = String

  type User = Account
  type Authority = models.poso.Permission

  val idTag: ClassTag[Id] = classTag[Id]

  val sessionTimeoutInSeconds: Int = 3600
  def resolveUser(id: Id)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[User]] = Future.successful(Cache.getAccountJson(id))

  def loginSucceeded(request: RequestHeader)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[SimpleResult] =
    Future.successful(Redirect(routes.Home.test))

  def logoutSucceeded(request: RequestHeader)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[SimpleResult] =
    Future.successful(Redirect(routes.Login2.login))

  def authenticationFailed(request: RequestHeader)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[SimpleResult] =
    Future.successful(Redirect(routes.Login2.login))

  def authorizationFailed(request: RequestHeader)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[SimpleResult] =
        Future.successful(Forbidden("no permission"))

 def authorize(user: User, authority: Authority, request: RequestHeader)(implicit ctx: ExecutionContext): Future[Boolean] = Future.successful {
    val perm = user.user.permissao.tree.get(request.path).getOrElse(false)
    perm match {
      case true => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

The Home action:

```
class Home @Inject() (implicit sessionService: SessionService) extends Controller with AuthElement with AuthConfigImpl {

  def test() = StackAction(AuthorityKey -> NormalUser) { implicit request =>
    {
      val u = loggedIn
      //usurio tem permissao
      Ok(views.html.home(u.user.email.toString))
      //      Ok(views.html.home(user.get.email.toString))
    }
  }

}
```

The login class:

```
class Login2 @Inject() (implicit sessionService: SessionService, loginService: LoginService, userService: UserService) extends Controller with LoginLogout with AuthConfigImpl with Logging {
 def authenticate = Action.async { implicit request =>
    {
      val form = userForm.bindFromRequest
      try {
        form.fold(
          errors => {
            Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.login("", userForm)))
          },
          other1Form => {
            val login = loginService.loginVerify(other1Form.email, other1Form.password)
            val uuidGenerate = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
            val account = userService.getDataFromUser(other1Form.email)
            Cache.addEntry(EhCacheRegion.Cerberus.toString() + SessionProductName.Account.toString(), uuidGenerate, models.poso.Session.toJson(account))
            gotoLoginSucceeded(uuidGenerate)
          })
      } catch {
        case login: LoginException => {
          val formError = form.withGlobalError(login.msg)
          Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.login("", formError)))
        }
        case ex: Exception => {
          logger.error(ex.getMessage())
          Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.login("", form.withGlobalError("system error"))))
        }
        case _: Any => {
          logger.error("error")
          Future.successful(BadRequest("err"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is the result on browser:
[image]

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have secure cookies set, and try to test in an unsecured environment. 
Check AuthConfig, for lazy val cookieSecureOption